# Excel find and replace: prepend a number to all rows that contain bold numbers in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel workbook. One of the columns has numbers like  439857, 2139, 32, 5943, etc. Just random numbers. Some of them though have bold font style.

I would like to prepend a single number, to all the numbers with bold font type in that column.

Is that possible, and how?

Example

Original column:

Column A

> **548976**
>
> **434**
>
> 5867
>
> **1845**
>
> 7
>
> 468345

Desired result after find replace:

Column A

> **2548976**
>
> **2434**
>
> 5867
>
> **21845**
>
> 7
>
> 468345

2 was added to the front of bold numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim r As Range, rng As Range
   Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))

   For Each r In rng
      If r.Value <> "" And r.Font.Bold = True Then
         r.Value = 2 & r.Value
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Note that because we are looking at a *Property* of the *Range* object, this is a no-go for *Conditional Formatting* or *Character* formatting.

Comment: Okay. I'll try it out and let you know later.